# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I am getting this error in  my React project:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

function Button({ label, backgroundColor = "red", size = "md", handleClick }) {
  let scale = 1;
  if (size === "sm") scale = 0.75;
  if (size === "lg") scale = 1.5;
  const style = {
    backgroundColor,
    padding: `${scale * 0.5}rem ${scale * 1}rem`,
    border: "none",
  };
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick} style={style}>
      {label}
    </button>
  );
}

Button.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
  size: PropTypes.oneOf(["sm", "md", "lg"]),
  handleClick: PropTypes.func,
};

export default Button;
```

///stories

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "./Button";

export default {
  title: "button",
  component: Button,
};
export const Red = () =>( <Button label="click" />);
```

i tried reinstalling the story book again...

Comment: Where is the error message shown (When building?  In the browser when running the code?) An error message normally shows additional information about where the problem occurs please show also this information.

Comment: running the code its  a run time error

Comment: do you have your stories in jsx/tsx files instead of js/ts?